# KeyAggrement in android not Acception ECPrivatekey

Tags: android

I got `java.security.InvalidKeyException`: No installed provider supports this key: `android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreECPrivateKey`
when i give

```
 KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH");
 keyAgreement.init(privateKey);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?